# Google StreetView Plug in for ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, google, google-street-view

I was using SIGIS Street & Bird View Version 2.5 for years in ArcGIS Desktop. It recently stopped working.  When the browser window opens I get a message to update my browser, but it is up to date.  I tried Chrome, Firefox, and Edge as my default browser but get the same error. MS Bird's Eye still works.

Is anyone having success with an ArcGIS Street View plugin?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced 10.7.1.

Comment: contact  co-founder & CTO of SIGGIS https://twitter.com/lieven_verheust?lang=en